# iOS build failure; /bin/sh No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, build, compiler-errors, sh

I was working on my application and then out of no where, I get this build error and can't figure out why it won't go away. Obviously it thinks I am missing a script of some sort. Anybody else know why? I am using Xcode 4.5.1.

> /bin/sh:
>   /Users/JonErickson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FireCom-cygbnsedlgybvdewalvvmzqeehlc/Build/Intermediates/FireCom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FireCom.build/Script-C8CC6BE415FAAB4C001BB67E.sh:
>   (null): bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check for a potentially corrupt "run script" phase in your project's "build phases".

It should look something like this:

[image: Build Phase]

Comment: Thats what I did. It's completely empty.

Comment: Ahh I fixed it. I didn't realize you could delete the run script. I didn't see the little gray "X" on "Run Script" header.

Answer (score 2):

I had renamed my app, and got into this error. In various places, I changed the name but couldn't find at one spot .. - in Target's build setting file.

Cmd + Shift + F to find in whole project.
searched for old App name string.
Found places where old name was still stuck, updated it with new name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this a number of times because my `DerivedData` isn't current with my work.  I've never understand the logic for when it does and does not keep track of changes I'm making... but since the script is trying to run from an archive in the derived data, you'll need to make sure the script is actually present.  To do this, delete your derived data (or at least the directory containing your script) and then build again.  Xcode will fill in the gap(s).  You can get quick access to `Derived Data` by navigating to the `File` menu and then going to `Project Settings` (or `Workspace Settings` accordingly) and following the link to your finder.  Just trash it.